# Print on two different pages using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two texts and i want to print them on two different pages, this is what i did so far :

**The button print :**

```
<button onclick="javascript : CallPrint('idText1','idText2')" type="button">Print</button>
```

**callPrint JavaScript method :**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CallPrint(firstText,secondText) {
        var firstContent = document.getElementById(firstText);
        var secondContent = document.getElementById(secondText);
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=1200,height=750,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,dir=ltr');
        WinPrint.document.write(firstContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.write(secondContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, they are printed one after the other. How is it possible to separate them on two different pages (without using br tags). If it is not possible, i wanna know if it is possible to show two print windows instead of one.

Comment: `to separate them on two different pages` - [CSS page breaks](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)

Comment: Have a look at the `page-break-after page-break-before page-break-inside` css properties and put them inside a @print css rule. There's some combination in there where you can force and element to always start a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty paragraph with `page-break-after: always` style between the 2 texts:

```
WinPrint.document.write(firstContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.write('<p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>');
WinPrint.document.write(secondContent.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open two windows in the function in order to seperate the contents in two files.

```
function CallPrint(firstText,secondText) {
        var firstContent = document.getElementById(firstText);
        var secondContent = document.getElementById(secondText);
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=1200,height=750,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,dir=ltr');
        WinPrint.document.write(firstContent.innerHTML);
        var WinPrint2 = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=1200,height=750,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,dir=ltr');
        WinPrint2.document.write(secondContent.innerHTML);
```

Comment: It did not work i've already tried it, i got an exception : cannot read property 'document' of undefined